# Fetch data from Google Spreadsheet between two dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to build a nodejs application, which will run once in every week. Its job is to fetch data from a Google Spreadsheet between last week and today. Basically, I want to get data added during last week.

I believe this is what I've to use: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet
but do let me know if there's something better.

I think `SpreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange()` will return an array with all the data but I am not sure where I can add some kind of query to fetch data by dates.

Something like

```
SpreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(date > lastWeek && date < today)
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: I have recently done quite a bit of work with the google sheet API, firstly I would say if there is any way at all of not using the spreadsheet to store data, use another way instead.

Secondly `getRange()` is used to get the data in a range of cells eg. A4-F17, it isn't a date range.

I don't think what you are after is possible just with the API, you may need to look at storing the last-row-downloaded somewhere in your db and then using getRange to start from that row.

Comment: Is there a way to know the date of column, when it was added?

Comment: Take a look at [Google Drive API changes()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes) or [revisions()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions). It would be a little more work, but you may find what you want there

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there's no way to know when a row was added, as such your range wouldn't work.

The way i would do this is keep a timestamp on each row for when it was added and iterate over all the data to find the values that fit. (You could also keep somewhere the last row read and start from there).

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name)
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
  if (data[i][index_of_timestamp] < today &&  data[i][index_of_timestamp] > lastWeek){
    realData.push(data[i]);
  }
}
```